# .htacess перенаправление

Tags: .htaccess

Столкнулся с задачей - нужно чтобы юзер мог жать по ссылке вида `site.ru/userlogin` и видел содержимое `user.php?login=userlogin`

сделал так:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?login=$1 [L,QSA]
```

но перенаправление идёт и с других страниц, например site.ru/view и тд. можно что-либо сделать? вид ссылок типа `site.ru/user/userlogin` **не** предлагать

Comment: 1. Другие ссылки, которые не нужно переадресовывать, как выглядят? 2. По этим ссылкам существуют реальные файлы на сервере?

Comment: site.ru/view - site.ru/view.php, site.ru/search - site.ru/search.php и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте через дополнительное условие, в котором укажите исключения

```
# тут нужно задать исключения
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/view|search|и_так_далее
# правило сработает, только, если в начале не будет view или search или ...
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?login=$1 [L,QSA]
```